# Selectively enabling Chameleon page templates on Plone

Tags: plone, chameleon

Reading https://pypi.python.org/pypi/five.pt/2.2.1

```
  To enable Chameleon, configure the package using ZCML:

   <include package="five.pt" />
```

Are Chameleon templates enabled per-package or globally? Instructions are little sparse.

If I want to enable Chameleon for a particular package only is it possible? (making migrating to Chameleon easier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote directly from the [PyPI page for the package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/five.pt):

> It works using monkey-patching onto the existing API (specifically, the `TALInterpreter` and `PageTemplate` classes). In simple terms, what the patching does is to replace the TAL interpreter class and make sure that the so-called "cooking" routine uses the Chameleon parser and compiler instead of the `zope.*` reference implementation.

So, when you load the `five.pt` package, the regular page templates code is patched to use Chameleon templates instead when templates are cooked (compiled).

That really precludes enabling Chameleon and disabling Chameleon on a package-by-package basis. Once **any** packages uses the `<include package="five.pt" />` directive, the `five.pt` `configure.zcml` file is loaded and the patch is applied.

That said, theoretically it *should* be possible to add per-package enabling or disabling back into the patch; the `__call__` and `cook` methods of the [`five.pt` `Program` utility](https://github.com/zopefoundation/five.pt/blob/master/src/five/pt/engine.py) would have to be taught how to detect what package the template applies to and make a decision on what `RepeatDict` class and page template object to use.